# Animation Starts but player won't move on key press in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Me and 3 friends started working on game and while codding run into error that animation on player starts but it won't move. We are working in Unity(C#)
I already checked for names in Animator and code so it's not it.

Here is a code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
       public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public Animator anim;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
        void Update()
    {
        Jump();
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f , 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0){
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }
    }




    void Jump(){
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")){
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f,5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

It's 2D game if It matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to create the rigidbody2d in start(), then try

```
rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2(moveSpeed,0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```